# Still get 64-bit warning on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone

I built an app for iOS a long time ago, but haven't done much with iOS so I'm a bit rusty. I'm now trying to update it to 64 bits and from what I've read, I mainly have to change the architecture to arm64, fix a few things and rebuild to update this, however I'm still getting the 64 bit warning on some of the simulators.

[image]

I get this message on some simulated devices but not all of them.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: try .. Build Active Architecture Only (Debug) - NO

Comment: @TonyMkenu I tried this but the app still appears on the list of "apps that may slow down your iPhone" in Settings -> General -> About -> Applications

Comment: Reset your simulator..